# Special kind of partition

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Consider $N := \{1,\ldots,n\} \subset \mathbb N$.
For a given $n$ I want to partition $N$ into subsets $\pi \in \Pi$ and count the number of possible partitions $|\Pi|(n)$.
Symmetric partitions should not be counted however.
Consider the following example:
\begin{align}
n = 2 : &\pi_1 = \{1,2\}, \pi_2 = \{12\}\\
n = 3 : &\pi_1 = \{1,2,3\}, \pi_2 = \{12,3\} = \{13,2\} = \{23,1\}, \pi_3 = \{123\}\\
n = 4 : &\pi_1 = \{1,2,3,4\}, \pi_2 = \{12,3,4\} = \{13,2,4\} \ldots, \pi_3 = \{123,4\},\ldots,\\ 
&\pi_4 = \{1234\}, \pi_5 = \{12,34\}, \ldots, 
\end{align}
such that $|\Pi|(2)=2$, $|\Pi|(3)=3$, $|\Pi|(4)=5$.
Is this number known?

Comment: When you say "symmetric partitions should not be counted" I take it then you mean this type of partition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: Exactly, right. Thanks.

Comment: Set notation is incorrect.  Find or invent an adequate notation.